# Fill in NA from one dataframe and add the rows not in first dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, merge, na

My question is similar to this question: [Fill in NA with other dataframe and then add the rows that are not in the first dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73496362/fill-in-na-with-other-dataframe-and-then-add-the-rows-that-are-not-in-the-first)

Such that I have two dataframes and I want to fill in `NA` values in the first dataframe based on values in the second dataframe and also append rows to the first dataframe from the second dataframe if they do not already exist. The key columns will be ID and Date.

I therefore have the following conditions:

1. If the `ID` and `Date` matches, the `NA` value will be replaced by second dataframe and existing values will not be replaced.
2. If the `ID` and `Date` does not matches, new row will be created
3. If the second dataframe contains columns which do not exist in the first dataframe, they are not included

## Primary

```
df1 = [['A','2021-03','NA',9,'NA'], ['B','2021-09','NA','NA',27], ['C','2021-12','5',12,28]]
df1_fin = pd.DataFrame(df1, columns=['ID','Date','Value_1','Value_2'])
```

## Secondary

```
df2 = [['A','2021-03',80,20,30], ['B','2021-09',90,'NA',20], ['B','2021-12','NA','NA',27], ['D','2020-06',4,12,28]]
df2_fin = pd.DataFrame(df2, columns=['ID','Date','Value_1','Value_2','Value_3'])
```

So based on the conditions above, my output dataframe looks like this:

```
ID  Date        Value_1     Value_2 
------------------------------------
A   2021-03     80          9   
B   2021-09     90          NA  
B   2021-12     NA          NA  
C   2021-12     5           12  
D   2020-06     4           12
```

Naturally, there are many ways I can do this (for example, I could use `fillna` to fill in the `NA` values in `df1` with values in `df2` based on matching `ID` and `Date`, and then check for `ID` and `Date` which are not in `df1` and perform a merge or append based on that)  but I am hoping for a more concise way to do it, perhaps similar to using `combine_first`. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mask the `NA` values then set the index of df1 and df2 to ID and Date and use combine first to fill the null values in df1 and add the missing rows for the combination of ID and Date

```
c = ['ID', 'Date']
(
    df1_fin[df1_fin != 'NA']
    .set_index(c)
    .combine_first(df2_fin.set_index(c))
    .reset_index()
    .reindex(columns=df1_fin.columns)
)
```

Result

```
  ID     Date Value_1 Value_2
0  A  2021-03      80       9
1  B  2021-09      90      NA
2  B  2021-12      NA      NA
3  C  2021-12       5      12
4  D  2020-06       4      12
```